# exec: "dnu": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-beta6

COPY project.json /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN ["dnu", "restore"]
COPY . /app

EXPOSE 5005
ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "project.json", "kestrel"]
```

I got the error when build the image

> exec: "dnu": executable file not found in $PATH

Even I change the last line as `ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "-p", "project.json", "web"]`

Comment: Try replacing the `RUN` line with `RUN dnu restore`. I have the feeling that for some reason, if you pass an array, it uses a different PATH to search for binaries.

Comment: @Augusto, did you mean `RUN ["dnu restore"]`? I got it from https://github.com/aspnet/Home/blob/dev/samples/1.0.0-beta6/HelloMvc/Dockerfile

Comment: no, just `RUN dnu restore`. You can see on the docker run [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) that the form that receives an array, doesn't spawn a shell (at least on linux, I assume it's similar on windows), and probably because of this, the path is not set properly to find the binary. Alternatively you might be able keep the current form, but you'll have to pass the full path to the `dnu` executable.

Comment: @Augusto, I tried `RUN dnu restore`. Same result. I want to try your alternatively way. How to pass the full path to the `dnu` executable? Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the 1.0.0-beta6 docker image is 100% broken and it doesn't contain the `dnu` or `dnx` binaries

```
$ docker run -it microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-beta6 /bin/bash
root@2cf36ce06b24:/# dnu --version
bash: dnu: command not found
root@2cf36ce06b24:/# dnx --version
bash: dnx: command not found
root@2cf36ce06b24:/#
```

And on beta7 (or beta8)

```
$ docker run -it microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-beta7 /bin/bash
root@b5cecfdb60e4:/# dnu --version
Microsoft .NET Development Utility
 Version:      1.0.0-beta7-15532
 Type:         Mono
 Architecture: x64
 OS Name:      Linux

root@b5cecfdb60e4:/# dnx --version
Microsoft .NET Execution environment
 Version:      1.0.0-beta7-15532
 Type:         Mono
 Architecture: x64
 OS Name:      Linux

root@b5cecfdb60e4:/#
```

So just use a newer image.